# Make a column with duplicated values into multiple dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a data frame that is called names as follows

```
Name,no1,no2
john,12,14
john,23,24
tom,24,26
tom,25,27
pat,15,16
pat,16,17
```

What I want to do is to have 3 data frames for `john`, `tom` and `pat`
meaning if i select `john`, it should display

```
12,14
23,24
```

How should I do this in R?
I am currently stuck at

```
john <- as.data.frame(myData, column.names = Name)
```

as I couldn't figure out or find a way anywhere to select `john` as it is not considered a row name but a value inside a row.

any help is much appreciated

Comment: Something like `split(df, df$Name)` should be what you want.

Comment: Or subsetting `subset(mydata, Name=="john")`

Comment: thank you Tim Biegeleisen and Jilber Urbina for the quick response. It helps and really appreciate it. Thank you